# Use Perl to process a text file based on the first field of each line

Tags: scripting, perl

I'm trying to write a Perl script that reads a file of the following form:

```
ATPG     TCD             tcd/T1, xxx/tcd/T2    
ATPG     INSTANCE        inst1/I1, xxx/inst2/I2, inst3/I3
ATPG     PATTERN         pat1/P1, pat2/P2
SIM      BLACKBOX        bb1/B1, bb2/B2
```

For each line that has `ATPG` in the first field, it should print to an output file. For example:

```
// TCD

read_core_description tcd/T1
read_core_description xxx/tcd/T2

// INSTANCE
add_core_instance  -instance inst1/I1  
add_core_instance  -instance xxx/inst2/I2   
add_core_instance  -instance inst3/I3

//PATTERN 
read_patterns pat1/P1  
read_patterns pat2/P2
```

Other lines like the ones starting with `SIM` don't affect the output file. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Please show what you have.  If you can't write code as basic as this then SO is probably not the best place to ask.  If that is the case, I suggest going through language basics first; you can learn enough for a problem like this in a few days.  Above all, simply asking for code is off-topic here.

Comment: @zdim: thanks for your notice, I will take as experience...

Comment: @Hanh Thank you for the note and for attribution.  It seems that the question was "_migrated_" here.  As for my comment -- here people generally expect very specific questions on _your code_. So you'd normally briefly describe what you are trying to do, show your code with its input and output (and possible errors), and state or explain what seems wrong and why. Otherwise questions are deemed off-topic.  Read over the short and useful help pages, starting with [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  For the future, as you say :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a one-liner, with descriptions shortened

```
perl -anE'
    BEGIN { %d = (TCD => "read", INSTANCE => "add", PATTERN => "patterns") 
    if (shift@F eq "ATPG") { $n=shift@F; say "// $n"; say "$d{$n} $_" for @F }
' input.txt
```

The `@F` is obtained for each line by splitting it on whitespace, so into words, by courtesy of `-a`.

I suggest to read the core description of the language and try it yourself.